# GlemTech DocumentUltimate 6.9.5 when run on linux server some pdf files open and some are showing the error PortableEngine supports Windows Only

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, model-view-controller, pdf-viewer, documentviewer

GlemTech DocumentUltimate 6.9.5 using ASP .NET Core when run on linux server some pdf files open and some are showing the error PortableEngine is currently supported only on Windows platform.
But Some PDF files as well as jpg files are opening

i want to open all the files in linux server using GlemTech DocumentUltimate version 6.9.5